# Python multidimensional array indexing explanation

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, numpy-ndarray

Could someone please explain to me what is happening here? I understand what is happening here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays, but do not understand this piece of code.

```
import numpy as np
y = np.zeros((3,3))
y = y.astype(np.int16)
y[1,1] = 1
x = np.ones((3,3))
t = (1-y).astype(np.int16)
print(t)
print(x[t])
x[(1-y).astype(np.int16)] = 0
print(x)
```

output:

```
[[1 1 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]

[[[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]]

[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: `x[t]` indexes a (3,3) on the first dimension with a (3,3) array; the result is (3,3,3), picking `x[0]` for one term, `x[1]` for others.  Since `x` is all 1s we don't see any pattern in the display, just the shape.

Comment: `x[t] = 0` assigns `0` to some elements of `x`.  The result is the same shape as `x`, not the (3,3,3) of `x[t]`.  `t` contains just 0 and 1, the result is that `x[0,:]` is set to 0.  So is `x[1,:]`, but `x[2,:]` is untouched.

Comment: Adding to what @hpaulj said, you can test it by setting `y = np.zeros((3,3)); x = np.ones((3,3)); x[1-y] = 0` and you will see `[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]`

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np              # Line 01
y = np.zeros((3,3))             # Line 02
y = y.astype(np.int16)          # Line 03
y[1,1] = 1                      # Line 04
x = np.ones((3,3))              # Line 05
t = (1-y).astype(np.int16)      # Line 06
print(t)                        # Line 07
print(x[t])                     # Line 08
x[(1-y).astype(np.int16)] = 0   # Line 09
print(x)                        # Line 10
```

**Line 02:**

Creates a two-dimensional 3 x 3 ndarray of zeros. `y` is a name that is made to point to this ndarray.

**Line 03:**

Sets the data-type of each element of `y`, to 16-bit integer.

**Line 04:**

Sets the element of `y` at the intersection of the middle row and middle column, to `1`.

**Line 05:**

Creates a two-dimensional 3 x 3 ndarray of ones. `x` is a name that is made to point to this ndarray.

**Line 06:**

The subtraction (`1-t`) results in several scalar subtractions (`1- elem`), where `elem` is each element of `t`. The result will be another ndarray, having the same shape as `t`, and having the result of the subtraction (`1- elem`), as its values. That is, the values of the ndarray `(1-t)` will be:

```
[[1-t[0,0], 1-t[0,1], 1-t[0,2]],
 [1-t[1,0], 1-t[1,1], 1-t[1,2]],
 [1-t[2,0], 1-t[2,1], 1-t[2,2]]]
```

Since `t` is full of zeros, and a lone `1` at the intersection of the middle row and middle column, `(1-t)` will be a two-dimensional ndarray full of ones, with a lone `0` at the intersection of the middle row and middle column.

**Line 07:**

Prints `t`

**Line 08:**

Things get a little tricky from here. What is happening here is called "Combined Advanced and Basic Indexing" (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing). Let's go through the specifics, step-by-step.
First, notice that `x`, is a two-dimensional ndarray, taking another integer ndarray `t` as an index. Since `x` needs two indices to be supplied, `t` will be taken to be the first of those two indices, and the second index will be implicitly assumed to be `:`. So, `x[t]` is first interpreted as `x[t,:]`. The presence of these two indices, where one index is an array of integers `t`, and the other index is a slice `:`, results in the situation that is called "Combined Advanced and Basic Indexing".

Now, what exactly happens in this "Combined" scenario? Here goes:
First, the shape of the result will get contributions from the first index `t`, as well as from the second index `:`. Now `t` has the shape `(3,3)`, and hence the contribution of `t` to the shape of the result of `x[t,:]`, is to supply the outermost (leftmost) dimensions of the result shape. Hence the result shape will begin with `(3,3,)`. Now, the contribution of `:` to the shape of `x[t,:]` is based on the answer to the question: On which dimension of `x` is the `:` being applied ? The answer is -- the second dimension (since `:` is the second index within `x[t,:]`). Hence the contribution of `:` to the result shape of `x[t,:]` is `3` (since `3` is the length of the second dimension of `x`). To recap, we have deduced that the result shape of `x[t]` will be that of `x[t,:]`, which in turn will be `(3,3,3)`. This means `x[t]` will be a three-dimensional array, even though `x` itself is only a two-dimensional array.

Note that in the shape `(3,3,3)` of the result, the first two `3`s were contributed by the advanced index `t`, and the last `3` was contributed by the implicit basic index `:`. These two indexes `t` and `:` also use different **ways** to arrive at their respective contributions. The `3,3`, contribution that came from the index `t` is just the shape of `t` itself. It doesn't care about the position of `t` among the indexes, in the expression `x[t,:]` (it doesn't care whether `t` occurs before `:` or `:` appears before `t`). The `3` contribution that came from the index `:` is the length of the **second** dimension of `x`, and we consider the **second** dimension of `x` because `:` is the **second** index in the expression `x[t,:]`. If `x` had the shape `(3,5)` instead of `(3,3)`, then the shape of `x[t,:]` would have been `(3,3,5)` instead of `(3,3,3)`.

Now that we've deduced the *shape* of the result of `x[t]` to be `(3,3,3)`, let us move on to understand how the *values* themselves will get determined, in the result. The values in the result are obviously the values at positions [0,0,0], 
 [0,0,1], [0,1,2], [0,1,0], [0,1,1], [0,1,2], [0,2,0], [0,2,1], [0,2,2], and so on. Let's walk through one example of these positions, and you will hopefully get the drift. For our example, let's look at the position [0,1,2] in the result. To get the value for this position, we will first index into the `t` array using the 0 and the 1. That is, we find out `t[0,1]`, which will be `1` (refer to the output of `print(t)`). This `1`, which was obtained at `t[0,1]`, shall be taken to be our first index into `x`. The second index into `x` will be `2` (remember that we are discussing the position `[0,1,2]` within the result, and trying to determine the value at that position). Now, given these first and second indices into `x`, we get from `x` the value to be populated at position `[0,1,2]` of `x[t]`.

Now, `x` is just full of ones. So, `x[t]` will only consist of ones, even though the shape of `x[t]` is `(3,3,3)`. To really test your understanding of what I've said so far, you need to fill `x` with diverse values:
So, temporarily, comment out Line 05, and have the following line in its place:

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))    # New version of Line 05
```

Now, you will find that `print(x[t])` at Line 08 gives you:

```
[[[3 4 5]
  [3 4 5]
  [3 4 5]]

 [[3 4 5]
  [0 1 2]
  [3 4 5]]

 [[3 4 5]
  [3 4 5]
  [3 4 5]]]
```

Against this output, test your understanding of what I've described above, about how the values in the result will get determined. (That is, if you've understood the above explanation of `x[t]`, you should be able to manually re-construct this same output as above, for `print (x[t])`.

**Line 09:**

Given the definition of `t` on Line 06, Line 09 is equivalent to `x[t]`, which, as we saw above, is equivalent to `x[t, :] = 0`.

And the effect of the assignment `x[t, :] = 0` is the same as the effect of `x[0:2, :] = 0`.

Why is this so? Simply because, in `x[t, :]`:

1. The index values generated by the index `t` are `0`s and `1`s (since `t` is an integer index array consisting of only `0`s and `1`s)
2. The index values generated by the index `:` are `0`, `1`, and `2`.
3. We are referring only to positions within `x` that correspond to combinations of these index values. That is, `x[t, :]` relates only to the those positions `x[i,j]`, where `i` takes values `0` or `1`, and `j` takes values `0`,`1`, or `2`. That is, `x[t, :]` relates only to the positions `x[0,0]`, `x[0,1]`, `x[0,2]`, `x[1,0]`, `x[1,1]`, `x[1,2]`, within the array `x`.
4. So, the assignment statement `x[t, :] = 0` assigns the value 0 at these positions in `x`. Effectively, we are assigning the value `0` into all three columns in the first two rows of `x`, and we are leaving the third row of `x` unchanged.

**Line 10:**

Prints the value of `x` after the above assignment.

Comment: While this is the combined advanced-basic, it is the simplest case, where is only one advanced index, the `t`.